# How to open base64 pdf in new window Android phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, phonegap-build

Hi There is a requirement, I need to open a base64 pdf file in new window of mobile browser using phonegap. I tried in many ways working in normal desktop browser but not phonegap Android application. Below I am giving syntax which is working in Desktop but not in Android.

```
window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + base64EncodedPDF);
```

How to achieve this functionality.

Comment: there's no way to preview a PDF from base64 in that way, not even with the in app browser plugin. The only option you have is to convert that base64 to a blob, then save it using the file plugin and finally display it in the native viewer with a plugin like https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Cordova Document Viewer Plugin https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer